# Unreliable behavior in Thymeleaf's th:selected attribute

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a project using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf for rendering html pages. In one of the pages, I have the following html to have Thymeleaf select an option:

```
<select name="value" id="usersWarning">
    <option value="0" th:text="#{button.disabled}">0</option>
    <option value="0.5" th:selected="${warning} == 0.5">50%</option>
    <option value="0.75" th:selected="${warning} == 0.75">75%</option>
    <option value="0.9" th:selected="${warning} == 0.9">90%</option>
    <option value="0.95" th:selected="${warning} == 0.95">95%</option>
</select>
```

Thymeleaf works as expected if warning equals 0.5 or 0.75, but if warning equals 0.9 or 0.95, Thymeleaf does not add the `selected` attribute to that option. I added the following option to see if my warning values are wrong:

```
<option th:text="${warning}"></option>
```

but in each case Thymeleaf shows 0.9 or 0.95 correctly.

Thank you for your help. This has been driving me crazy for the last hour.

Comment: It's probably because of a rounding error in your floating point comparison. You could try rounding the value of warning to two digits and comparing as string or figuring out if you can use Apache Commons Precision.compareTo() in your expression.

Comment: @Kylos Thank you for your suggestion. You were right, though I fixed it by using value.compareTo(warning) == 0 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend trying

```
${#numbers.formatDecimal(warning, 0, 2) == '0.95'}
```

This should format the number as a string with two decimal digits allowing you to perform string comparison on the result.

This might be necessary because floating point comparisons can have very small rounding errors that cause a strict comparison to fail. Formatting as string rounds the number to fewer decimal places and gets rid of the small error that would otherwise cause the comparison to fail.